# 3 cronjobs, 15 minute intervals, 5 minutes apart

Tags: php, timer, cron, cpanel

So what I want to do is have 3 cronjobs running. But I want it to be like this:

1st cronjob: Starts :00 every hour, and runs every 15 minute. So it will be :00, :15, :30, :45, :00

2nd cronjob: Starts :05 every hour, and runs every 15 minutes. So it will be: :05, :20, :35, :50, :05

3rd cronjob: Starts :10 every hour, and runs every 15 minutes. So it will be: :10, :25, :40, :55, :10

What is the correct syntax for these 3? I only find out how to start them at :00, :05, :10 but how do i make them run every 15 minutes? Constantly, 24/7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do

```
*/15 * * * * /command/to/execute >/dev/null 2>&1
5,20,35,50 * * * * /command/to/execute >/dev/null 2>&1
10,25,40,55 * * * * /command/to/execute >/dev/null 2>&1
```